# How to have option in Nautilus right-click menu to executed/open as root?

Tags: nautilus, files, root, customization

I would like to make it so that in Nautilus when I right-click on something which can only be executed or opened as root then I get an option to do so and then it just prompts me for my password rather than me having to go into Terminal and then either run or open it manually or run Nautilus as root which is not advised.

Is there a way to add such an option? Actually, preferably if the file can be run as root and opened as root as well, then I would like to have two options (e.g.: if a source file can be opened and edited but also executed). So not just one option if another is available.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is provided by the package `nautilus-admin`.  Just install it and you will have an entry in the right-click menu `Open as Adminstrator` (or `Edit as Administrator` as appropriate)
.

Comment: Will it also give me an option to execute programs as administrator if said program can be executed?

Comment: Um, I have to admit that I don't know where executable programs are stored in Ubuntu....so don't know how to test.

Comment: In the `/bin` directory.

Comment: When I right click on files in /bin like `bzip2` I get `Edit as Administrator` so that's probably not what you want.

Comment: No, the app is not designed to run binaries or scripts as root. The package's  description tells you specifically what it does. A small flaw in the app is it doesn't differentiate between files that gedit can edit vs those it can't like binaries.

Comment: Yes, I did have a look at that and didn't think so. So is there nothing else which would add the additional functionality?